# Getting rid of corruption

Tags: terraria-mobile

I'm a hard mode mobile terraria player. I have 2 amazing worlds(my main ones). But both of them are being over-run by the corruption. I've tried powder, but it always comes back. Is there any way to get rid of it or contain it?

Answer (score 1):

**I may be completely wrong but:**
You can contain it by ensuring there is space between the corruption and your normal world (area you don't want to be corrupt). For late-game, you'll have to have a border of at least 2/3 layers of non-corruptible materials, such as clay.

To clear it out - Simply remove all Ebonystone and purify everything.

*Note: A 'border' means several spaces of air, followed by the clay border.*

Answer (score 1):

[Sunflowers stop the spread of corruption.](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Sunflower)

You can use [Purification Powder](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Purification_Powder) to push the corruption back, but if you want to keep it back, you could simply use sunflowers. The same goes for the [Crimson.](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Crimson)